# Athena returns different result sets when exactly the same query is run

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

When I run exactly the same query multiple times on the same data-set (the very same parquet files on s3), slightly different result sets are returned each time. Sometimes a few lines are missing or aggregated data is slightly off etc. Granted, the query is relatively complex with several nested queries and aggregations that runs on a subset of partitions but I don't understand why query results can differ. Is there a query-result-consistency type of setting that I am not aware of?

Comment: There is no change to your s3 data/partitions metadata behind your table when you are running queries?

Comment: There is no change to your s3 data/partitions.

Comment: Could you prove with a general idea of how your query looks like, please?) And what are the differences?)

Comment: I'm dealing with the same problem, have you already fixed it?

Comment: no, I am afraid not. I moved on with a different approach to the problem. Do consider Nebulastic's answer below. It's usually the case.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is pretty old, but i has faced the same problem with a complex query that uses row_number function. My data has no a primary key, and the row_number partition clausule  took only a few fields like criteria in orderby. I solved the problem including all the "key" fields in the orderby clausule of partition row_number function. Now, i receive the correct row count over the query.
Important show that before this, in a amout of data of 1M rows, the count result variad ~100 rows.
I couldn't put this as a comment because the stackoverflow reputation limit.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to have an example query and example layout of your data. The first thing that comes into mind is that data is being appended to the parquet file continuously, but you confirmed that this is not the case.

If you have a lot of partitions, it could be that Athena did not yet load some of those partitions (automatically). While the partitions may be there, Athena also needs to load those partitions into the internal Athena data catalog. It could be that some of those partitions are still missing in this data catalog and thus not used when running the query. The result is then that your aggregations are slightly off.

You could try the following and then run your query again a few times and see if the result still changes:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

More information can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-empty-results/).